# Are Touma's parents ever revealed?

Tags: qed

Are Touma's Parents in Q.E.D. ever revealed? 
I have read a chapter where they were apparently going to meet however his parents had to leave due to certain circumstances.

The English Translated Manga has no such chapter but is there one in the non translated versions as I think the Manga has ended as it is mentioned so on Wikipedia?